# Error when making device connect to Kaa middleware

Tags: kaa

I've recently setup a Kaa docker environment to use for development/testing.

I can successfully generate a SDK for my endpoint, and make it connect the first time.

But when i restart the kaa docker container i get the following error from the endpoint logs when connecting endpoint:
I/*ultOperationTcpChannel: Can't sync. Channel [default_operation_tcp_channel] is waiting for CONNACK message + KAASYNC message

The Kaa log contains the following error:

```
    2017-02-15 20:52:27,305 [pool-9-thread-2] TRACE o.k.k.s.b.s.t.BootstrapTransportService - Message processing failed
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_112]
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.common.endpoint.security.MessageEncoderDecoder.decodeSessionKey(MessageEncoderDecoder.java:189) ~[endpoint-shared-0.10.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.common.endpoint.security.MessageEncoderDecoder.decodeData(MessageEncoderDecoder.java:218) ~[endpoint-shared-0.10.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.bootstrap.service.transport.BootstrapTransportService$BootstrapMessageHandler$1.decodeEncryptedRequest(BootstrapTransportService.java:269) ~[kaa-node-0.10.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.bootstrap.service.transport.BootstrapTransportService$BootstrapMessageHandler$1.decodeRequest(BootstrapTransportService.java:250) ~[kaa-node-0.10.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.bootstrap.service.transport.BootstrapTransportService$BootstrapMessageHandler$1.run(BootstrapTransportService.java:185) ~[kaa-node-0.10.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

I've set the docker compose file to use persistent storage for sql and nosql databases.

Regenerating the SDK again, solves the problem until next reboot of Kaa.

Comment: Turns out there is a missing volume in the Kaa's docker setup - resulting in the certificates being regenerated on each restart of the docker image.

Had to add:
kaa-data:/usr/lib/kaa-node/keys

to ensure keys are persisted to volume.